# How do I merge two django db's?

Tags: python, django, database-migration

I have two instances of the same Django app. I need to merge the data in these DBs to one DB.

I considered Natural Key fixtures, but I have many objects whose natural key involves fields from a related model, so they are not being serialized when I am serializing using natural keys.

For example

```
class Account(models.Model):
    #fields...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, parent_link=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    def natural_key(self):
        return self.user.natural_key()
    natural_key.dependencies = ["User"]
```

This account's fixture:

```
 >./manage.py dumpdata --natural-primary --natural-foreign backend.Account
 $ {"fields": {"country": "Angola", "birth": "1991-02-18", "facebook_id": 213321}, "model": "backend.account", "pk": 547}
```

(notice it does not contain it's natural key, since it is not a part of the model)

What is the best way to merge data from two identical Django apps?

**Edit:**

To clarify, I have my data, and the instances have different values, but (in some cases) the same primary keys -since they are in different DBs. I want to have all my data (the instances and their related objects) in the same DB.

Comment: how exactly do two databases figure in this?

Comment: @e4c5, you're right, I added an explantion

Comment: Do these two models are referencing to same `User` model?

Comment: @scriptmonster, No, Accounts from db A and from db B have references to different users. But the Account model is only one example. Many of my models are interconnected, and have foreign keys that define them (and are a part of the natural key)

Comment: This question is far too broad. I suggest that you delete it and ask another one. Leave django out of it. This sort of task is carried out best with SQL tools. Remember to post your table structures (clearly indicating the foreign key fields). Tag the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue, two identical websites sharing several models but with different objects.
Unfortunately, merging them by natural_key was impossible.

I had to implement a new django commands similar to loaddata, in order to **append all models** from the second website into the first one.

```
import os
import warnings
from collections import defaultdict

from django.core.management import CommandError
from django.core.management.utils import parse_apps_and_model_labels
from django.core.management.commands.loaddata import Command as LoadDataCommand, humanize
from django.core.management.color import no_style
from django.db import (
    DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, DatabaseError, IntegrityError, connections, router
)

from django.core import serializers
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models.fields.related import RelatedField, ManyToManyField


class Command(LoadDataCommand):
    help = 'Installs the named fixture(s) in the database.'
    missing_args_message = (
        "No database fixture specified. Please provide the path of at least "
        "one fixture in the command line."
    )

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('args', metavar='fixture', nargs='+', help='Fixture labels.')
        parser.add_argument(
            '--database', default=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS,
            help='Nominates a specific database to load fixtures into. Defaults to the "default" database.',
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '--app', dest='app_label',
            help='Only look for fixtures in the specified app.',
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '-e', '--exclude', action='append', default=[],
            help='An app_label or app_label.ModelName to exclude. Can be used multiple times.',
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '--format',
            help='Format of serialized data when reading from stdin.',
        )

    # TODO delete equals to overridden
    def handle(self, *fixture_labels, **options):
        self.using = options['database']
        self.app_label = options['app_label']
        self.verbosity = options['verbosity']
        self.excluded_models, self.excluded_apps = parse_apps_and_model_labels(options['exclude'])
        self.format = options['format']

        with transaction.atomic(using=self.using):
            self.appenddata(fixture_labels)

        # Close the DB connection -- unless we're still in a transaction. This
        # is required as a workaround for an edge case in MySQL: if the same
        # connection is used to create tables, load data, and query, the query
        # can return incorrect results. See Django #7572, MySQL #37735.
        if transaction.get_autocommit(self.using):
            connections[self.using].close()

    def appenddata(self, fixture_labels):
        # Most of the code is used only to manage transaction and fixture file format reuser it and override load_label instead
        self.loaddata(fixture_labels)

    def load_label(self, fixture_label):
        """Load fixtures files for a given label."""
        self.objs_idx = ObjectDict()
        self.objects = []
        self.show_progress = self.verbosity >= 3
        self.deferred_m2m = []

        for fixture_file, fixture_dir, fixture_name in self.find_fixtures(fixture_label):
            _, ser_fmt, cmp_fmt = self.parse_name(os.path.basename(fixture_file))
            open_method, mode = self.compression_formats[cmp_fmt]
            fixture = open_method(fixture_file, mode)
            try:
                self.fixture_count += 1
                objects_in_fixture = 0
                loaded_objects_in_fixture = 0
                if self.verbosity >= 2:
                    self.stdout.write(
                        "Installing %s fixture '%s' from %s."
                        % (ser_fmt, fixture_name, humanize(fixture_dir))
                    )

                objects = serializers.deserialize(
                    ser_fmt, fixture, using=self.using, ignorenonexistent=True,
                    handle_forward_references=False,
                )

                for obj in objects:
                    objects_in_fixture += 1
                    if (obj.object._meta.app_config in self.excluded_apps or
                            type(obj.object) in self.excluded_models):
                        continue
                    if router.allow_migrate_model(self.using, obj.object.__class__):
                        loaded_objects_in_fixture += 1
                        self.models.add(obj.object.__class__)
                        # Load all fixture in memory
                        self.objs_idx.append_deserialized_object(obj)
                        self.objects.append(obj)
                    if obj.deferred_fields:
                        self.objs_with_deferred_fields.append(obj)
                if objects and self.show_progress:
                    self.stdout.write('')  # add a newline after progress indicator
                self.loaded_object_count += loaded_objects_in_fixture
                self.fixture_object_count += objects_in_fixture
            except Exception as e:
                if not isinstance(e, CommandError):
                    e.args = ("Problem installing fixture '%s': %s" % (fixture_file, e),)
                raise e
            finally:
                fixture.close()

            # Warn if the fixture we loaded contains 0 objects.
            if objects_in_fixture == 0:
                warnings.warn(
                    "No fixture data found for '%s'. (File format may be "
                    "invalid.)" % fixture_name,
                    RuntimeWarning
                )
        # Once you have all object in memory you can load them
        for obj in self.objects:
            self.process_object(obj.object)
        if self.verbosity >= 1:
            self.stdout.write('... All objects saved ...')
        # Once all objects have been save (append mode) and new pks have been assigned add m2m relations
        for obj, field_attname, related_pk in self.deferred_m2m:
            attr = getattr(obj, field_attname)
            attr.add(related_pk)
            if self.verbosity >= 3:
                self.stdout.write('Adding relation for field {0}: {1} -> {2}'.format(field_attname, obj.pk, related_pk))
        # Disabled for security reason
        # raise ValueError('Disabled')

    def process_object(self, obj):
        if obj is None:
            raise ValueError('None object in process object')

        old_pk = obj.pk
        new_pk = self.objs_idx[obj]['new_pk']
        # Object has been save yet no work
        if new_pk:
            return new_pk

        self.manage_related_field(obj)

        if self.verbosity >= 2:
            self.stdout.write('Saving object: (%s, %s)' % (obj.__class__, obj))
        obj.pk = None
        try:
            obj.save(using=self.using)
            if self.show_progress:
                self.stdout.write(
                    '\rSaving object: (%s, %s)' % (obj.__class__, obj),
                    ending=''
                )
        # psycopg2 raises ValueError if data contains NUL chars.
        except (DatabaseError, IntegrityError, ValueError) as e:
            e.args = ("Could not load %(app_label)s.%(object_name)s(pk=%(pk)s): %(error_msg)s" % {
                'app_label': obj.object._meta.app_label,
                'object_name': obj.object._meta.object_name,
                'pk': obj.object.pk,
                'error_msg': e,
            },)
            raise
        self.objs_idx.data[obj._meta.model][old_pk]['new_pk'] = obj.pk
        return obj.pk

    def manage_related_field(self, obj):
        related_fields = [field for field in obj._meta.get_fields() if isinstance(field, RelatedField)]
        if len(related_fields) > 0:  # has not related field
            for field in related_fields:
                if field.related_model in self.excluded_models:
                    continue

                if type(field) is ManyToManyField:
                    attr = getattr(obj, field.attname)
                    attr.clear()
                    m2m_pks = self.objs_idx[obj]['deserialized_object'].m2m_data[field.name]
                    for m2m_pk in m2m_pks:
                        related_obj = self.objs_idx.data[field.related_model][m2m_pk]['object']
                        new_related_pk = self.process_object(related_obj)
                        self.deferred_m2m.append((obj, field.attname, new_related_pk))
                        # attr.add(new_related_pk)
                else:
                    related_obj = self.objs_idx.data[field.related_model][getattr(obj, field.attname)]['object']
                    if related_obj is not None:
                        new_related_pk = self.process_object(related_obj)
                        setattr(obj, field.attname, new_related_pk)


class ObjectDict(object):
    """
    Dictionary to easily retrieve fixture object based on class and their original primary key
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: {'new_pk': None, 'object': None}))

    @staticmethod
    def from_deserialized_objects(deserialized_objects):
        instance = ObjectDict()
        for deserialized_object in deserialized_objects:
            instance.append_deserialized_object(deserialized_object)
        return instance

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.data[item._meta.model][item.old_pk]

    def append_deserialized_object(self, deserialized_object):
        obj = deserialized_object.object
        setattr(obj, 'old_pk', obj.pk)
        self[obj]['object'] = obj
        self[obj]['deserialized_object'] = deserialized_object
```

I suggest you to test everything in the django default test DB, with this TestCase.
It uses a pre dumped fixture file from the django app (using python manage.py dumpdata) to populate the test DB, after that it applies the custom command to append all object from other database fixture dumps.

```
from collections import defaultdict

from django.core import serializers
from django.core.management.utils import parse_apps_and_model_labels
from django.test import Client, TestCase
from utils.tests import reverse
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.test import TestCase
from django.apps import apps

from apps.commons.accounts.models import User
from apps.commons.accounts.tests import MultiUserTestCase

class TestCustomCommands(TestCase):
    # Create fixture from the primary database to test everything
    fixtures = ['tmp/dump/test_append_data_fixtures_pre.json']

    def test_appenddata(self):
        fixture_to_import = 'tmp/dump/fixtures_to_import.json'
        excludes = ['sites.Site']
        # Counts objects before appenddata per model
        count_pre = {}
        for model in apps.get_models():
            count_pre[model] = model.objects.count()

        self.excluded_models, self.excluded_apps = parse_apps_and_model_labels(excludes)

        # Counts objects to append per model
        with open(fixture_to_import, 'r') as f:
            objects = serializers.deserialize('json', f, ignorenonexistent=True)
            count_new = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
            for obj in objects:
                if obj.object._meta.model in excludes:
                    continue
                count_new[obj.object._meta.model] += 1

        command = ['appenddata', fixture_to_import]
        for exclude in excludes:
            command += ['-e', exclude]
        command += ['-v', '0']
        call_command(*command)

        # Verify with count that all objects have been imported
        for model in apps.get_models():
            self.assertEqual(count_pre[model] + count_new[model], model.objects.count(), msg='Count mismatch for model %s' % model)
```

Example of test (appending data from Website2 into Website1):

```
# Website 1
python manage.py dumpdata app1 app2 ... > test_append_data_fixtures_pre.json

# Website 2
python manage.py dumpdata app1 app2 ... > fixture_to_import.json

# Website 1, run the provided test
python manage.py test TestCustomCommands.test_appenddata
```

Example of usage (appending data from Website2 into Website1):

```
# Website 1
python manage.py appenddata fixture_to_import.json
```